# checking if a sentence contains Symbols

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
string="I can't wait for Christmas!!"
other_symbols='''!()-[]{};:\<>/?#$%^&*_~'''
if other_symbols in string:
   print('wrong')
else:
   print('right')
```

It is supposed to ignore every symbol other than `@` and my output should be wrong but I keep getting right.

Comment: `if any(symbol in cavs for symbol in other_symbols)`. Your check checks if `'''!()-[]{};:\<>/?#$%^&*_~'''` is a substring of `"LET'S GO!! @cavs"` which is clearly false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `any` to check if any of the symbols in `other_symbols` is in `cavs`. Better make `cavs` a set too for `O(1)` membership tests:

```
sc = set(cavs)
if any(i in sc for i in other_symbols):
    print("wrong")
else:
    print("right")
```

Or, as [@Steven Rumbalski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322401/steven-rumbalski) pointed out in a comment, you could reverse it and make `other_symbols` a set and do:

```
if any(c in other_symbols for c in cavs):
    # rest similar
```

This would be an improvement if there were multiple sentences to test since you wouldn't have to create a set for each sentence.

Comment: thanks but i cant use any or set in my code, since we never learned anything about it in my class

Comment: Then just don't wrap it in a `set` @CAVS, just do `any(i in cavs for i in other_symbols)`. :)